# How to add thumbnails and views

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, thumbnails

Is there a way I can add thumbnail and views to this feed? The feed is [here](http://youtube.zxq.net/test7.html)

And here is the part of the code that needs transformation.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("body").append("<div id = 'data'><ul>jffnfjnkj</ul></div>");
        var dataContainer = $("#data ul");
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/sony/uploads?alt=jsonc&v=2&callback=?',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data){

                     $.each(data.data.items, 
                               function(i, val) {

                                 if (typeof(val.player) !== 'undefined' && typeof(val.title) !== 'undefined') {
                                    dataContainer.append('<li><a href='+val.player["default"]+' target="_blank">'+val.title+'</a></li>');
                                 }
                         });
                    }
                });
            });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, like this

```
dataContainer.append('<li><img src="'+val.thumbnail.sqDefault+'" width="120" height="90" alt="'+val.title+'"/><a href='+val.player["default"]+' target="_blank">'+val.title+'</a>Views '+val.viewCount+'</li>');
```

Titel above and views below thumbs

```
dataContainer.append('<li><a href='+val.player["default"]+' target="_blank">'+val.title+'</a><br /><img src="'+val.thumbnail.sqDefault+'" width="120" height="90" alt="'+val.title+'"/><br />Views '+val.viewCount+'</li>');
```

Comment: That works. is there a way to make the title appear above the thumbnail and the views appear below the thumbnail?

Comment: Sure. look at the answer